# Firestore cloud function: Get DocumentSnapshot from the event

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm listening for change events of collection documents, just making a dump what I'm receiving:

```
func ForwardUserChanged(ctx context.Context, e cloudfn.FirestoreEvent) error {
    raw, err := json.Marshal(e.Value.Fields)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(string(raw))

    return nil
}
```

where `FirestoreEvent` is a custom struct:

```
// FirestoreEvent is the payload of a Firestore event.
type FirestoreEvent struct {
    OldValue   FirestoreValue `json:"oldValue"`
    Value      FirestoreValue `json:"value"`
    UpdateMask struct {
        FieldPaths []string `json:"fieldPaths"`
    } `json:"updateMask"`
}

type FirestoreValue struct {
    CreateTime time.Time `json:"createTime"`
    Fields     map[string]interface{} `json:"fields"`
    Name       string                 `json:"name"`
    UpdateTime time.Time              `json:"updateTime"`
}
```

What I want is a simple way of decoding the `Fields` into my struct, which was saved into the in the same collection before. 
The thing is that the `Fields` looks in a pretty complex way and it's not just an easy mapping map[string]interface{} to the struct fields. For example, the `Fields` looks like this:

```
{"answers":
  {"mapValue":
    {"fields":
      {"fish-1":
        {"mapValue":
          {"fields":{"option":{"stringValue":"yes"},
```

but the original struct is

```
type Report struct {
  Answers map[string]Answer
}

type Answer struct {
  Option string
}
```

Is there an easy way to de-serialize the map into the struct? Or it should be done "by hand"?

There should be a way to get a `DocumentSnapshot` from this data. The data from the Firestore look like the protobuf message and it even can be seen in the `Document` struct from the `google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/firestore/v1`.

Answer (score 0):

After not finding other solutions to handle the event Fields, I decided to post my solution here in case others, like me, were looking.

Keep in mind my solution has some issues, I just haven't had to address them yet.

- At some point it will have to be refactored into a recursive call so that the mapValue and arrayValue types can go as deep as they need to.
- It should probably have better error checking.

```
    type FirestoreValue struct {
        CreateTime time.Time `json:"createTime"`
        // Fields is the data for this value. The type depends on the format of your
        // database. Log an interface{} value and inspect the result to see a JSON
        // representation of your database fields.
        Fields     map[string]interface{} `json:"fields"` // I changed this to a map[string]interface{} instead of the example codes interface{}
        Name       string                 `json:"name"`
        UpdateTime time.Time              `json:"updateTime"`
    }
    
    func (fv *FirestoreValue) Recombobulate(destination interface{}) error {
        result := make(map[string]interface{})
        for fieldName, infVal := range fv.Fields {
            for typeKey, val := range infVal.(map[string]interface{}) {
                switch typeKey {
                case "stringValue":
                    result[fieldName] = val
                case "booleanValue":
                    result[fieldName] = val
                case "integerValue":
                    // I saw firestore give me this once: integerValue: "1"
                    sVal, ok := val.(string)
                    if ok {
                        result[fieldName], _ = strconv.Atoi(sVal)
                    } else {
                        result[fieldName] = val
                    }
                case "doubleValue":
                    result[fieldName] = val
                case "timestampValue":
                    result[fieldName], _ = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, val.(string))
                case "referenceValue": // this is just a string for all intents and purposes
                    result[fieldName] = val
                case "nullValue":
                    // not really sure what to do with this one
                    result[fieldName] = val
                case "arrayValue":
                    elements := val.(map[string]interface{})["values"]
                    var innards []interface{}
                    for _, ele := range elements.([]interface{}) {
                        for _, eleInterf := range ele.(map[string]interface{}) {
                            innards = append(innards, eleInterf)
                        }
                    }
                    result[fieldName] = innards
                case "mapValue":
                    mapFields := val.(map[string]interface{})["fields"]
                    innards := make(map[string]interface{})
                    for mapKeyName, v := range mapFields.(map[string]interface{}) {
                        for _, innard := range v.(map[string]interface{}) {
                            innards[mapKeyName] = innard
                        }
                    }
                    result[fieldName] = innards
                case "geoPointValue": // this is just a map[string]int/float
                    innards := make(map[string]interface{})
                    for mapKeyName, v := range val.(map[string]interface{}) {
                        innards[mapKeyName] = v
                    }
                    result[fieldName] = innards
                }
            }
        }
    
        
        mapstructure.Decode(result, &destination)
        return nil
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It's typical with code that deals with Cloud Firestore for it to manually copy the values from a DocumentSnapshot into a data structure of your own definition.

The exception to this is with Java code, where the Firestore SDK can use reflection to automatically map field values to and from POJO properties.  But not everyone chooses this, as they might need to modify the values going in and out.  But I don't think the Firestore SDKs for other languages have this sort of support.